# How to create a JButton with only an image

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have made some buttons with JButton and I tried to add an image to the button without seeing the rest of the button, so you only see the image which is clickable. This is my code:

```
 final JButton HomeButton = new JButton("Home");
HomeButton.setBorderPainted(false);
HomeButton.setBorder(null);
HomeButton.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
HomeButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
HomeButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("src/Images/0.png")));  << Line 78
HomeButton.setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("src/Images/0_h.png")));
HomeButton.setBounds(new Rectangle(10, 9, 50, 50));
this.contentPane.add(HomeButton);
```

And I get this error when using it:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
at gui.Gui.<init>(Gui.java:78)
at gui.Gui$1.run(Gui.java:40)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: *"..because I am new to java swing and gui's. .."* ..and could not be bothered searching or consulting the documentation?

Comment: I already have searched for a long time, and I couldn't find it. but can nobody react to my question now it's put on hold?

Comment: *"I already have searched for a long time,"*  (chuckle) Wish I had a dollar for every time I've heard that claim.  The best way to indicate you have done research is to write a good question (possibly linking some of the research you found). *"can nobody react to my question"* If by 'react' you mean comment, yes we can.  If you mean 'answer' then no.  Not unless it is 'reopen'd.

Comment: Okay, next time I will show that I have done research. Okay, I meant comment. But what can I improve to get it reopened again?

Comment: I have fixed it! I did it this way: I used the things from the answer from Melih Altintas and I did this for the images: CloseButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Images/0.png"))); so now it can load the images from inside the jar. What do you think of this way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JButton button = new JButton();
button.setBorderPainted(false);
button.setBorder(null);
button.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
button.setIcon(myIcon1);
button.setRolloverIcon(myIcon2);
button.setPressedIcon(myIcon3);
button.setDisabledIcon(myIcon4);
```

Comment: I did this:HomeButton.setIcon("Images/0.png"); and I get this error:The method setIcon(Icon) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (String), what do I have to do?

Comment: try : setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/0.png"))); @xX4m4zingXx

Comment: I have this now: HomeButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("src/Images/0.png"))); and I get nullpointerexception. but I am sure that my image is at src/Images/0.png

Comment: @xX4m4zingXx Never reference "src" within you paths, it won't exist when the application built and packaged. Make sure you path's case is exactly correct, when using Class#getResource, the search is case sensitive

Comment: @MadProgrammer I remove the "src" in the path, but I still get the error message and my background is in the same directory and my path to that background is "src/Images/Background.jpg" and the background does work. http://prntscr.com/6airoe

Comment: @xX4m4zingXx Then the images aren't where you think they are

Comment: @MadProgrammer This is the absolute path: C:\Users\Ruud\workspace\ExileLauncher\src\Images\0.png, but how am I going to do this when I make a jar from it?

Comment: @xX4m4zingXx Also make sure the images are been included within the resulting jar.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Okay, I understand that. but what do i have to change to get this error fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the button border...

```
button.setBorderPainted(false);
```

Remove the content painting...

```
button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
```

You may even want to make the button transparent...

```
button.setOpaque(false);
```

Depending on your needs, you might also want to remove the focus rectangle...

```
button.setFocusPainted(false);
```

You may also find you need to reset the button margins to make the button fit the content...

```
button.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

See [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more details