# Why are my JButtons not transparent after using the setOpaque() function?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel, imageicon

I've set my JButtons to be transparent and I added pictures with transparent background to them, but they refuse to become transparent. Moreover, it works on Windows but does not work on my MacBook.

I tried

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < champions.size(); i++) {    
    JButton B = new JButton();  
    B.setActionCommand(champions.get(i).getName());
    B.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(140,196));
    B.setBackground(new Color(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f));
    B.setOpaque(false);
    B.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    B.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    B.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Images/"+champions.get(i).getName()+ ".png"));
    B.setRolloverEnabled(false);
    buttons.add(B);
    panel2.add(B);
}
```

So basically, I tried every way of setting it to transparency, but nothing worked!!!

Comment: Maybe all these [other Stack Overflow questions](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+JButton+transparent+macos&atb=v344-1&ia=web) covering the same topic might help.

Comment: Don't do `B.setBackground(new Color(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f));` or `B.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(140,196));` and maybe do something more like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732022/how-to-create-a-jbutton-with-only-an-image/28732051#28732051)